# How to uninstall django-watson library clearly

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, uninstallation, django-watson

I want use search library in django

So i decide to use django-watson(it tell me easy install, easy use)

I command

```
git clone https://github.com/etianen/django-watson.git
```

in my django projects

and insert `watson` in my `settings.py. INSTALLED_APPS`

when I command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

django can't find `watson` so I decide uninstall `django-watson` and reinstall

I command

```
rm -rf django-watson
```

and command `migrate` (check about when i was uninstall library migrate has no problem)

```
python manage.py migrate
```

suddenly it show me error for me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
    File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
django.setup()
    File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
    File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
mod = import_module(mod_path)
    File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'django-watson'
```

I think it has installed in env but i can't find where is `django-watson`

I want remove `django-watson` clearly

please somebody help me

Comment: You have to remove it from your `settings.py` too.

Comment: thank you @4140tm I solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have removed it from INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and that you have removed all imports related to it inside your project.

Answer (score 0):

As said, you have to remove `django-watson` from your installed apps. But that was the original mistake: to install watson, you have to add `watson` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, not `django-watson`. [This is well explained in the documentation](https://github.com/etianen/django-watson/wiki):

> 1. Install django-watson using pip: pip install django-watson.
> 2. Add 'watson' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.